# Use Ansible to launch new EC2 instance into cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ecs

What I want to do is use Ansible to create an ECS cluster, then create an EC2 instance and launch it into that cluster, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. I've had no trouble launching and configuring an EC2 instance on its own so far, but it's this next step that's totally blocking me.

The AWS documentation says I can create an EC2 instance with User Data to assign it to a cluster, but this doesn't seem to work when I use the user_data field of Ansible's ec2 module. This is what I have in that field:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=my-test-cluster" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

I feel like there must just be something I'm not seeing, or else some basic understanding I'm missing. I'm hoping someone can provide some pointers here.

Edit: I wasn't originally using the right ECS-optimized AMI, but even after starting an instance with the correct image I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is the proper policy on the instance to associate itself with the cluster. It sounds like you have the rest of it setup fine. I would safely assume that if you logged into the server and checked the ECS logs from the agent that you would see permission issues.

Take a look here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html I had a similar issue myself before and setting the proper permissions fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that [your instance doesn't have Internet access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html):

> Container instances need external network access to communicate with the Amazon ECS service endpoint, so if your container instances do not have public IP addresses, then they must use network address translation (NAT) to provide this access.